# Clarkson's inequalities for Banach space valued functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In standard analysis, Clarkson's inequalities expresses the norms of the sum and difference of two functions in $L^p$ in terms of the norms of the individual functions. In particular, one may use the inequalities to prove that $L^p$ is uniformly convex. Now, if one considers functions valued in a Banach space X, one may introduce the norm
$$
||f||_p=\left(\int||f(x)||^p_Xd\mu(x)\right)^{1/p}.
$$ 
With suitable conditions on the Banach space X, I guess that one may prove Clarkson's inequalities for Banach space valued functions (with respect to the above norm). However, I have not been able to find a reference for this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A necessary condition for $X$ is super-reflexivity as this property is inherited by closed subspaces. Indeed, once you prove that $L_p(X)$ is uniformly convex, $X$ identified with the space of constant functions, will be super-reflexive as well.

Comment: You may also find this paper useful: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4587.pdf